# python: have a default value when formatting strings (str.format() method)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Is there a way to have a default value when doing string formatting? For example:

```
s = "Text {0} here, and text {1} there"
s.format('foo', 'bar')
```

What I'm looking for is setting a default value for a numbered index, so that it can be skipped in the placeholder, e.g. *something* like this:

```
s = "Text {0:'default text'} here, and text {1} there"
```

I checked https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings and didn't find what I need, maybe looking in the wrong place?

Thanks.

Comment: Under what conditions would you expect that default text to be used?  How would it be possible for index 0 to be missing, yet index 1 be present?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it within the format string itself, but using named placeholders, you can pass a `dict`-like thing to `.format_map` that contains a generic default value, or combine a `dict` of defaults for each value with the provided `dict` to override individually.

Examples:

1. With a defaulting `dict`-like thing:

   ```
   from collections import Counter

   fmt_str = "I have {spam} cans of spam and {eggs} eggs."

   print(fmt_str.format_map(Counter(eggs=2)))
   ```

   outputs `I have 0 cans of spam and 2 eggs.`
2. With combining `dict` of defaults:

   ```
   def format_groceries(**kwargs):
       defaults = {"spam": 0, "eggs": 0, **kwargs}  # Defaults are replaced if kwargs includes same key
       return "I have {spam} cans of spam and {eggs} eggs.".format(defaults)

   print(format_groceries(eggs=2))
   ```

   which behaves the same way.

With numbered placeholders, the solutions end up uglier and less intuitive, e.g.:

```
def format_up_to_two_things(*args)
    if len(args) < 2:
        args = ('default text', *args)
    return "Text {0} here, and text {1} there".format(*args)
```

The tutorial doesn't really go into this because 99% of the time, modern Python is using f-strings, and actual f-strings generally don't need to deal with this case, since they're working with arbitrary expressions that either work or don't work, there's no concept of passing an incomplete set of placeholders to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you only needed to insert an exact number of values positionally

as a lambda

```
meh = lambda x='default x',y='default y': 'Text {0} here, Text {1} here'.format(x,y)
print(meh(3,7))
```

as a function

```
def meh(x='default x',y='default y'):
  return "Text {0} here, Text {1}".format(x,y)
print(meh(3,7))
```